# Android fragments list, only the firs elements renders in portrait mode

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a problem when creating a Fragment list

This is my state (I tried a lot)

```
public class RecipesFragment extends Fragment {
//...

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setView();
//...

private void setView() {
    _dbHandle = new Database(this.getContext());
    _recipesLogic = new RecipesLogic(_dbHandle);

    List<RecepieDBModel> data = _recipesLogic.GetAllRecepies();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        try {
            RecepieDBModel tmpData = data.get(i);
            ImagePanelFragment imagePanelFragment = new ImagePanelFragment("", tmpData.Title + i, tmpData.Components);
            final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.recipes_table_layout, new SpacerFragment(), "fragment:" + UUID.randomUUID());
            transaction.add(R.id.recipes_table_layout, imagePanelFragment, "fragment:" + UUID.randomUUID());
            transaction.commit();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
}
```

The problem here is that in portrait mode I get only the SpacerFragment (just a fixed height fragment) - the first fragment - and when I flip it to landscape it shows everything (the correct amount of fragments)
[image]
I tried to invalidate elements, refreshDrawableState etc. and now I'm lost

Could somebody give me a tip on how I could resolve or try to resolve this problem?

Comment: Ok, I found a new thing each time I flip the screen new Fragments are added. 
In general, I have 2 rows from the DB
So each time I flip I get 2 new rows (horizontal) blank and the 2 from the DB are at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

ok I got my answer, just use RecyclerView.Adapter